# how do i get a stored procedure result to use on another stored procedure or query statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure where inside the procedure is a query statement which its result will be used as a parameter for another query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getRecActive`(
IN  adminid VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
   select record_id from records2 where record_div = @adminid
   //i want to use record_id result to the next query
   select * from records where record = "record_id";
END
```

Comment: So..? Can you provide more information?

Comment: Why is it tagged PHP if you didn't show us any PHP code?

Comment: adminid and @adminid are not the same thing.

Comment: how do i get the record_id field result in the first query and use it in the where clause in the second query. w/0 using joint statements or use in or not in statements

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from records 
where record in
(
  select record_id from records2 where record_div = @adminid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this as a procedure then you need to select into a local variable and use that in your second query. given

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | photo    |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | aaa      | john.png |
|  2 | Jane     | jane.png |
|  3 | Ali      |          |
+----+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE p(
IN  adminid VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
    declare vid int;
   select id into vid from users where username = adminid;

   select id,username,photo from users where id = vid;
END $$

delimiter ;

call p('aaa')

+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | photo    |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | aaa      | john.png |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Note you cannot stuff a result set into a variable and what you are trying to do won't work at all if thats what you get back from your first query.